# How to avoid line breaks in header tags?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, electron

I am using header tags, and I don't want line breaks after them.

I tried to use the `display: inline;` property, but it didn't work.

HTML:

```
<h5>Token No.:</h5> <h4>147</h4>
```

CSS:

```
h5 {
    display: inline;
}
```

This should result in no line breaks, but it gives one after "Token no.:"

Answer (score 5):

You need both h4 and h5 display inline, may be need set `!important` for overriding other selector

```
h5, h4 {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

Updated:

If you want only affect to current section you can move to a div with class

```
<div class='token'>
   <h5>Token No.:</h5> <h4>147</h4>
</div>
```

css

```
.token h5, .token h4 {
        display: inline !important;
 }
```

```css
h5, h4 {
    display: inline !important;
}
```

```html
<h5>Token No.:</h5> <h4>147</h4>
```

Comment: do you want both h4 and h5 in only one line?

Comment: I updated answer, please try to add !important to css

Comment: remains unaffected

Comment: you can wrap a class inside an use this css

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)

Answer (score 1):

you also need to put `display:inline` for `h4` as well.

[js fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/47rz6bf9/)

```
h5, h4 {
  display: inline;
}
```

Comment: Try to put it at the end of your css file and make sure that css file is the last one in <head> after any css style you might have

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

The line break that you're seeing is actually being caused by the inherent vertical margins above and below each of the heading tags; you can eliminate this by setting `margin: 0` on both `h4` and `h5`:

```css
h4, h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<h5>Token No.:</h5>
<h4>147</h4>
```

Comment: Then that sounds like a [**specificity**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) issue; you can see it working in my example above. You likely need to increase the selector's specificity. Without seeing your code I can't state exactly what you would need for this, but you can always use generic boosts such as `body h4`, for example.

Comment: How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to know that `h1`, `h2`, `h3`... have their own native style, that's why words in those tags can be bigger.

If you want to show text inline, its always better to use `<span>`.

```html
<span>Token No.:</span> <span>147</span>
```

Comment: They meant `<span>`

Comment: @UdasiTharani I have updated my answer, please review.

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

The most clean method to perform this is

```
<h5>Token No.: <span>147</span></h5>
```

Note heading tags are default block level element so whenever you stack vertically heading tags one after another it takes entire width and break the line every heading tags. So I have used inline-level element inside the block level element so it doesn't break. Inline level element stack horizontally one after another.

```html
<span>1</span><span>2</span><span>3</span><span>4</span><span>5</span>
```

But block level element stack vertically

```html
<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
```

So if you do not want to break line in your HTML you should probably define `display: inline` to those both heading tags. You have set only h5 to `dislay: inline;`. You need to set both to display inline or set `float: left;` to h5 will work.

```css
h5, h4 { float: left}
```

```html
<h5>Token No.: </h5> <h4> 147</h4>
```

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a wrapper for your code and use the display: flex property as follows

```
<section class="section-wrapper">
<h5>Token No.:</h5>
<h4>147</h4>
</section>


<style> <!-- No need to use <style> tags if you have a seperate css file -->
    .section-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi! I am extremely sorry to tell you that there was a typo error! I am so humbled and thankful for you having put in your time and energy into helping me! :)